# How can i make normals on an imported mesh face the right way?

Tags: python, vertices, import, normals

I'm writing an addon to import a model from a game, and it works for the most part, but some of the meshes always end up with their normals facing the wrong way no matter what i do.
The format i'm reading does store vertex normals but i can't make Blender respect them. I'm building a mesh using bmesh, and i tried to just set normals for each vertex (and print out a few of them) like so:

```
...
        m = bpy.data.meshes.new(name = "Mesh")
        bm = bmesh.new()
        if (i == 1): print("\n\n\nBMESH NORMALS:\n")
        for j, vCo in enumerate(verts):
            newVert = bm.verts.new(vCo)
            newVert.normal = normals[j]
            if ( (i == 1) and (j < 10) ): print(newVert.normal)
...
        bm.to_mesh(m)
        obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name = modelName, object_data = m)
        if (i == 1):
            print("\n\n\nFINAL NORMALS:\n")
            for j, v in enumerate(obj.data.vertices):
                if (j < 10): print(v.normal)
...
```

But once i convert bmesh to mesh, the normals just get autogenerated, and facing the wrong way, as evident by the output:

```
BMESH NORMALS:

<Vector (0.6406, -0.1016, 0.7422)>
<Vector (0.6797, -0.1094, 0.7031)>
<Vector (0.3438, -0.1484, 0.9141)>
<Vector (0.7031, -0.1016, 0.6797)>
<Vector (0.8047, -0.0547, 0.5625)>
<Vector (0.7891, -0.0391, 0.5859)>
<Vector (0.6016, -0.0938, 0.7734)>
<Vector (0.7969, -0.0859, 0.5781)>
<Vector (0.6797, -0.7109, -0.1328)>
<Vector (0.7578, -0.6406, -0.0469)>

FINAL NORMALS:

<Vector (-0.6540, 0.0934, -0.7507)>
<Vector (-0.6924, 0.0994, -0.7147)>
<Vector (-0.3529, 0.1458, -0.9242)>
<Vector (-0.7150, 0.0943, -0.6928)>
<Vector (-0.8185, 0.0494, -0.5723)>
<Vector (-0.7989, 0.0314, -0.6007)>
<Vector (-0.6148, 0.0850, -0.7841)>
<Vector (-0.8045, 0.0747, -0.5892)>
<Vector (-0.8720, 0.1207, -0.4744)>
<Vector (-0.8490, 0.0365, -0.5272)>
```

What does setting a normal for a bmesh vert even do if they just get discarded?
Anyway, i read that mostly people use custom split normals data to import custom normals. So i tried using this code to generate it:

```
...
        m.use_auto_smooth = True
        m.create_normals_split()
        loopNormals = list( range( len(m.loops) ) )
        for loop in m.loops:
            loop_vIdx = loop.vertex_index
            loop.normal = normals[loop_vIdx]
            loopNormals[ loop.index ] = loop.normal
        m.normals_split_custom_set(loopNormals)
...
```

But even that doesn't seem to work. I actually can't even find where exactly is this custom split data stored, but i think that if i call calc_normals_split() on the mesh i'm supposed to be able to read them from loop normals? Well, here's a screenshot (normals display is on), supposedly the normal on that vertex should match, or at least be closer to the imported normal, but it's still facing in the opposite direction.
[image: Text]
I don't understand it. Of course i can just flip normals on this mesh manually, and maybe i can compare imported normals with the generated ones to do that automatically, but how do i actually get Blender to utilize the imported normals?